# Complex conjugation does not change rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-rank

I have a question about complex conjugation of a matrix. Prove that for any rectangular matrix $A$ the following holds

> rank $A = \text{rank} \, A^*$ where $A^*$ is complex conjugate transpose of $A$.

Comment: Do you already know that the rank of the transposed matrix is the same as the rank of the original? Then you need only show that conjugation doesn't change the rank.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think the point of my question is why the complex conjugate does not change the rank of the matrix.

Comment: What ways to characterise or determine the rank do you know?

Comment: yes, the normal way is to use Gaussian elimination or Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Comment: Do you already know that Gauss(-Jordan) elimination is basically multiplication with matrices of special simple form? If so, the observation that $\overline{A}\cdot \overline{B} = \overline{A\cdot B}$ makes it rather immediate.

Comment: "matrices of special simple form" do you mean identity matrix?? I still do not get your point, sorry.

Comment: No, I meant the matrices that swap two rows, that multiply a row by a scalar, and that add one row to another. The matrices that produce the elementary row-operations. If you also use column operations, those are obtained by multiplying (on the right) by matrices of the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal M$ be the space of matrices of a certain size.

Prove that $f\colon \mathcal M\to \mathcal M, A\mapsto \overline A$ is a transformation that doesn't change the dimension of the nullity.

Then use the [Rank-nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Conjugation isn't $\mathbb{C}$-linear, it's $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear (doesn't matter for the main point, of course).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\in F^{n\times n}.$ If $A$ invertible, then $\bar A$ invertible, therefore $rank(\bar A)=rank(A)$.

Let $U=PA$ where $U$ is the $\textrm{rref}(A)$ and $P$ is invertible.

Now since the number of pivot column(s) of $\bar U$ is the same as $U$, so $\textrm{rank}(\bar U)=\textrm{rank}(U).$

So $\textrm{rank}(A)=\textrm{rank}(PA)=\textrm{rank}(U)=\textrm{rank}(\bar U)=\textrm{rank}(\overline{PA})=\textrm{rank}(\bar P\bar A)=\textrm{rank}(\bar A).$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way to show $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(\overline{A})$. After this , Since $A^*=(\overline{A})^T$ , if you already know [$\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1337691) , it follows that

$$\text{rank}(A^*) = \text{rank}(A^*)^T = \text{rank}(\overline{A}) = \text{rank}(A).$$

Let $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$, and suppose $\text{rank}(A) = r$, so there are $r$ independent columns of $A$. $\text{basis}(A) = \{x _j + y_j:j\in J  = \{i_1,\cdots,i_r\} \}$ form the basis of the column space, where $x$ and $y$ contain the real and imaginary parts of the column respectively. Let
$U = \{x_{k}+y_{k} :  k \in K = \{i_{r+1},\cdots,i_n\} \}$ be the rest of the columns .
By linear independence

$$\sum_{j\in J} c_j(x_j+y_j) = 0 \implies c_j=0, \qquad \forall j\in J \tag{1}$$

Since $U \subseteq \text{span}(\text{basis}(A))$

$$x_k+y_k = \sum_{j\in J} c_{k,j}(x_j+y_j), \qquad \forall k \in K  \tag{2}$$

Consider $\overline{A}$, which some of its columns are denoted as $\overline{\text{basis}(A)} = \{x _j-y_j:j\in J  = \{1,...,r\} \}$. We claim that $\overline{\text{basis}(A)}$ is a basis for the column space of $\overline A$. Let $\sum_{j\in J} b_j(x_j-y_j) = 0 $, and conjugate both sides to get $\sum_{j\in J} \overline{b_j} (x_j+y_j) = 0 $  which implies $ \overline{b_j}=0$ for $\forall j\in J$ by $(1)$. This leads to $b_j=0$ for $\forall j\in J$. So

$$\sum_{j\in J} b_j(x_j-y_j) = 0 \implies b_j=0, \qquad \forall j\in J $$

which means $\overline{\text{basis}(A)}$ is independent. Consider the rest of the columns
$\overline{U} = \{x_{k}-y_{k} :  k \in K = \{i_{r+1},...,i_{n}\} \}$. Conjugating both sides of $(2)$, we have $x_k-y_k = \sum_{j\in J} \overline{c_{k,j}}(x_j-y_j)$ , so
$\overline{U} \subseteq \text{span}(\overline{\text{basis}(A)})$.
These two last points imply that $\overline{\text{basis}(A)} = \text{basis}(\overline{A}) $ .

We conclude that

\begin{align}
\text{rank}(A) &= \dim(\text{span}(\text{basis}(A))) \\
&= |\text{basis}(A)| \\
&= |\text{basis}(\overline{A})| \\
&= \dim(\text{span}(\text{basis}(\overline{A}))) \\
&= \text{rank}(\overline{A})
\end{align}