# How to prove the rank of the conjugate transpose equals the original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A\in\Bbb C^{n \times n}$,I want to prove $\text{rank} A=\text{rank} A^H$ where $A^H$ is the conjugate transpose matrix of $A$. We only need to prove:

> $\text{rank} A=\text{rank} \bar A$

where $\bar A$ is the conjugate matrix of $A$. I have tried but was not able to solve the problem.

---

I found a similar question here [rank of complex conjugate transpose matrix property proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490434/rank-of-complex-conjugate-transpose-matrix-property-proof). I know rank-nullity theorem, but I have not learn any theorem about maps that preserve the dimension of nullity. How do we prove $A \to \bar A$ map preserves dimension of nullity?

Comment: $Ax=0$ iff $\bar A\bar x=\bar 0=0$.

Comment: if $A$ is a matrix representing a linear transformation, then the physical meaning of conjugate transpose is the matrix for the adjoint of the transformation. Hope this helps!

Comment: done? to prove what A.G. says pick any vector in the kernel of A and compute $\langle Av, v \rangle $.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' hints! I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is the reduced row echelon form for $A$, then we know that $U=FA$ for some invertible matrix $A$. Since matrix multiplication cannot increase the rank,
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rk}
\rk(A)=\rk(F^{-1}FA)\le\rk(FA)\le\rk(A)
$$
so $\rk(A)=\rk(U)$. Similarly, $\rk(A^H)=\rk(U^H)$, because $F^H$ is invertible.

Thus you only need to show that $U$ and $U^H$ have equal rank. It's easy to see that the nonzero columns of $U^H$ are linearly independent; their number is the same as the number of pivot columns of $U$, which is the rank of $U$.