# Unexpected applications of row rank = column rank

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, matrix-rank

The fact that the row rank of a matrix is the same as the column rank is quite surprising (to me atleast, hopefully to you too!).

> I am looking for unexpected applications of this fundamental fact, and
>   would prefer if the applications are easily accessible to laymen, say
>   like applications in recreational math. Does not have to be completely
>   basic, though, it is targeted to bright high school students.

Related question on this site: [Looking for an intuitive explanation why the row rank is equal to the column rank for a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran)

This is a temporary computer, so I might not be able to respond. So thank you all in advance.