# Rank of the given pattern matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence

Consider the following $7 \times 7$ matrix. Every unfilled entry is a $0$. What's the rank of this matrix?

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
2 &  & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 3 &  & 3 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 4 &  & 4 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 5 &  & 5 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 6 &  & 6 \\
 &  &  &  &  & 7 &  
\end{bmatrix}  $$

If we solve it using brute force, that is, by multiplying the scalars $c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_7$ to the column vectors and equating with $0$, we can get the rank. But is there any better way to do this? Looking at the pattern, I feel, there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. The rank of a matrix is invariant under row and column operations (see eg. [Row & Column Operation to Determine Rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471930/row-column-operation-to-determine-rank)). So doing the row operations
$$R_3 \to R_3 - 3 R_1,$$
$$R_5 \to R_5 - \tfrac{5}{3} R_3,$$
$$R_7 \to R_7 - \tfrac{7}{5}R_5$$
in that order gets us to
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
2 &  & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 3 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 4 &  & 4 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 5 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 6 &  & 6 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  
\end{bmatrix}  $$
and then applying the column operations
$$C_3 \to C_3 - C_1,$$
$$C_5 \to C_5 - C_3,$$
$$C_7 \to C_7 - C_5$$
in that order gets us to the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 & 1 &  &  &  &  &  \\
2 &  & &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 3 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 4 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 5 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 6 &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Comment: Just to confirm, the rank is $6$?

Comment: Yes, that's right