# How can the row rank and column rank be equal here?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I don't understand how this is equal.

[image]

I can see three pivots so that makes it a rank 3 regarding the columns. Hence, the first three columns are **pivot columns**, so the matrix has a **column** **rank 3**.

But how is the **row rank** equal to three? To have a row rank of three, shouldn't the entire column 4 consist of [0,0,0,0]? Could someone explain to me what I am missing here?

For me, the definition of a pivot = `[1,0,0,0]` (so having a one and all others are zero), but when I'd check the row, I can see a `[1,0,0,4]`, which is not equal to what I stated above!

Can someone help me comprehend it? Clearly I am missing something here...

Comment: row rank = column rank. All three rows a linearly independent.

Comment: What is your **definition** of "row rank"?

Comment: If the three row vectors were linearly dependent, then so were their projections from $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$.

Comment: I still don't get it. Could someone explain this me a bit simpler or with an example? My definition of a row rank is to check it as I check it in the column rank... I think that pivot = rank and clearly, that 4 on the end suggests it's not a pivot anymore, thus I can't see how the rank is being a 3...

Comment: Related, and maybe helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran