# Rank of matrix equals dimension of range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

I came across a statement 
"Clearly, the rank of $A$ is the dimension of the range of the linear transformation $f :X \to Ax$",
and I want the justification or proof?

My definition of rank: The rank of a matrix A is the common value of
the row rank of A and the column rank of A.

Comment: Often times, the rank of a matrix is defined as the dimension of the image of the associated linear transformation. So for us to help you, you need to specify which definition of rank you're using (there are many equivalent ones).

Comment: Please give your definition of rank.

Comment: A starting definition for rank is often the dimension of the column space for a matrix A. The column space is the range.

Comment: I edited the question for the definition of rank

Comment: For your consideration: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran

Comment: @giobrach I know that row-rank(A)=column-rank of A , but my question is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we are given that the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ has column-rank (and therefore coincident row-rank) $r$.  That is, the maximal set of linearly independent columns of $A$ contains $r$ vectors.  It follows that the span of the columns of $A$, henceforth the column space of $A$, is an $r$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^m$.

It now suffices to show that the range of the linear transformation $f:x \mapsto Ax$ is precisely the same subspace.  From there, we would see that saying "the column space is $r$-dimesional" is ("clearly") equivalent to saying that "the range of $f$ is $r$-dimensional".  To see that this is the case, we proceed as follows.

Let $\mathbf a_1,\dots,\mathbf a_n$ denote the columns of $A$. Consider an arbitrary element $y$ inside the column space of $A$. By definition, this mean that there exist coefficients $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that
$$
y = x_1 \mathbf a_1 + x_2 \mathbf a_2 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf a_n.
$$
Note that we can rewrite the above sum as a product.  In particular, we have
$$
y = \pmatrix{\mathbf a_1 & \mathbf a_2 & \cdots & \mathbf a_n} \pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} = Ax
$$
where $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)^T \in \Bbb R^{n}$.  So, any element $y$ from the column space of $A$ is also an element of the range of $f$.

By following this idea in reverse, we see that any element $y$ in the range of $f$ has the form $y = f(x) = Ax$, which means that we have $y = x_1 \mathbf a_1 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf a_n$ like before.  That is, $y$ is an element of the columns space of $A$.