# dimension of column space in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am confused why the dimension of the column space of a matrix is the number of pivotal columns? Could anyone elaborate it by some concrete examples? BTW, could you also elaborate a bit about why number of pivotal columns = number of pivotal rows? Is it related to A and A^T? I don't quite understand what does pivotal mean here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer gives the explanation that I find clearest and easiest to understand: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332945/169852

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very helpful answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That the dimension of the column space equals that of the row space is a nontrivial theorem.  The pivots are the leading $1$'s ($1$'s with only zeros below it), after row-reduction.  Consider $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{pmatrix}$.  After row-reduction/gaussian elimination, we get $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$.  There are two leading $1$'s, so two pivot columns, and the dimension of the column/row space is two.  Thus we can say the *rank* is two.

Comment: I think i understand this problem. Thanks a lot!