# Space generated by lines/columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

"Is it possible to find a 3x3 matrix such that the dimension of the space generated by the line-vector is different from the generated by the column-vector?"

I think that there is a more clever way to solve this problem, but my approach was to noticed that, if it exist, the dimensions are 2 for line/columns and 1 for columns/line. Suppose the dimension of the vector line is one, so that we can reduce the matrix to
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu a & \mu b & \mu c\\ 
a & b & c\\ 
 0& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

But we can notice that the columns vector is also LD, so that it is also 1D. The contrary is also true.

Even if this is right, i want to know if there is another way to prove/disprove it, and for considering cases with matrix whose dimensions > 3

Comment: What is a line vector?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Probably "row vector."

Comment: I think you are basically asking whether the "row rank" and "column rank" of a matrix can be different. The answer is no; this has been discussed on this website before, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran).