# If a set of row vectors are linearly independent and the matrix of those row vectors is a square matrix, does it means the same of column vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

If a set of row vectors are linearly independent and the matrix of those row vectors is a square matrix, does it means the set of column vectors are linearly independent and vice versa?

I already know that if A is not a square matrix, then there're some examples which the row vectors are linearly independent and the column vectors are not(linearly dependent), but I do not sure if the statement is true when A is a square matrix.

Can someone help me to figure out this questions or give me some counter examples or algebraic proof?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the columns are also linearly independent and vice versa!

This is a special case of the fact that, for all matrices, *column rank and row rank are equal* (see many explanations for this fact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran)).

If the row vectors are linearly independent, then $A$ has full row rank. Therefore, $A$ has full column rank. Therefore, the columns of $A$ are linearly independent!