# A,B matrices and column space

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

if **A,B**  have the same column space , does that means they have the same number of rows and the same rank?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 4):

It does mean the matrices have the same number of rows since otherwise one would not be able to compare the column spaces. E.g.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Furthermore it also means that the rank is the same. For this look at why [the row rank equals the column rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332908/looking-for-an-intuitive-explanation-why-the-row-rank-is-equal-to-the-column-ran) (and the column rank just being the dimension of the column space)