# Is it a property of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector space $V$, if $\rm\ v\in V\ $ then $\rm\ w\in V\ \iff\ w+c\:v\in V\:.\ $

Could anyone tell me why? Is it an axiom of vector space, that it's closed under addition and multiplication? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Subspaces_and_quotient_spaces), a subspace has to be closed under addition and multiplication, but it doesn't say a word about whether the same applies to vector spaces.

Comment: What is $c$ here? And for the case that $w\notin V$, how is $w+cv$ even defined?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20210/290354

Comment: Here is a very narrow-minded answer: if you know something is true for subspaces of any vector space, then it must also be true for any vector space, because $V$ is a subspace of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Subspaces are vector spaces. So you can definitely state that a vector space is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. (Actually this last fact follows directly from vector spaces' axioms.)

Answer (score 0):

did you check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) part of the wiki page?

vector spaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication (i'm assuming your c is a scalar)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, a subspace is in particular a vector space so if it characterizes a subspace that is a vector space it is also a property for vector spaces. Also, under addition it is a group and under multiplication it is a semi group so it is closed under linear combinations of elements.

Answer (score 0):

cv is a member of V by closure under scaler multiplication. Then, w + cv is a member of V by closure under vector addition (since cv has been shown to be a vector in V).

Going the other way, we can still deduce that cv is a member of V, and similarly so is -cv. So, by closure under vector addition, (w + cv) + (-cv) = w, w is also a vector in V.